# How to add custom notification sound - Ionic 4

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, ionic4

I am using the FCM plugin together with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Notifications are sent by making an http call to a Cloud Function from which the notification is sent using the device token.

The cloud function looks like this:

```
  let payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Pedido completado',
                body: 'Gracias por usar nuestro servicio!',
                sound: 'boop.mp3',
                priority: "high",
                icon: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/....Moviapp_icono_512x512.png'
            }
        };

admin.messaging().sendToDevice([token], payload);
```

My component.ts looks like this

```
  async getToken(uid) {
    const token = await this.fcm.getToken();
    const body = { token, usuario: uid };
    this.sentTokenToTheServer(body);
  }

  async sendPushNotification(token) {
    const pushURL = `https://us...cloudfunctions.net/pushNotification?token=${token}`;
    this.http.get(pushURL, { responseType: 'text' }).toPromise();
  }
```

Notifications work correctly even with a custom icon, but the problem is the sound that remains by default

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add your mp3 file inside src/assets folder. then add this in config.xml file

```
<resource-file src="src/assets/boop.mp3" target="app/src/main/res/raw/boop.mp3" />
```

then notification payload should be like this

```
{
  "notification":{
  "title":"Pedido completado",
  "body":"Gracias por usar nuestro servicio!",
  "sound":"boop.mp3",
  "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
  "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me the setup for  ios ? whare to store the sound and how ?

Answer (score 0):

For the latest android versions you need to create a notification channel if you'd like to use a custom sound. The documentation of the FCM plugin describes how to do that.